# How to set properties of custom controls xamarin forms in xaml

Tags: xamarin.forms

My goal is to set the properties of custom controls from a Page using xaml. I'm attempting to create a custom set of menu items, that all look the same but each one contains a different title. How could I set the title of each menu item from Xaml?
For Example sake, Ive simplified my actual code from the project to something simple.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
    <local:CustomControl someCustomAccessor="some text">
```

While setting the property for the custom control like this:

```
    class CustomControl: ContentView{

    private string someText { get; set; }

    public static BindableProperty TitleProperty = BindableProperty.CreateAttached("someCustomAccessor", typeof(string), typeof(CustomControl), null, BindingMode.TwoWay);

    public CustomControl()
    {
        Content = new Label
        {
            Text = someText
        };
    }

    private string someCustomAccessor
    {
        get { return someText; }
        set { someText = value; }
    }
}
```

I've looked everywhere for something like this and have come up short. Please help.

Comment: you need to make your property public

Comment: Thats exactly it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done something similar to this, but drawing on my Silverlight experience...

The .CreateAttached("someCustomAccessor"  ....

Tells the binding engine to look for a Public property called someCustomAccessor, yours is currently private and will need to be Public.  Also change the casing to be SomeCustomAccessor.

Also, the Binder doesn't know that it's a string, so it will need to be cast and set appropriately in the get;set;

```
public string SomeCustomAccessor
{
    get { (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
    set { SetValue(TitleProperty, value); }
}
```

Also the binding in your example is TwoWay, it may only need to be OneWay, but you can change that once you've got it working.